Data sets missing after migration
We had to migrate Superset to a new server while upgrading from V1.3 to V3.13.  We also moved the database (PostgreSQL 15) containing the datasets for many (150) charts to a new server. We updated the connection for the database. Now when we open a dashboard containing the charts, they show as expected but when we edit any of the charts, the dataset for the chart is missing. The charts show in the charts list with the correct title and dataset but when we edit a chart both the dataset is shown as missing and even the title is blank.  Any ideas for what's wrong / how to fix?
We have tried to copy the dashboards while copying the charts.  The copied charts have missing datasets too.  We have tried resaving the database connection information.  We have tried debug logging.  There are no entries posted in the log when we edit any of the charts.  We have tried resaving the datasets with no changes and resaving after forcing refreshes of the schema and the table. Nothing that we tried reestablished the datasets for the charts.

We received a solution on Superset Github: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/30329 In brief, we needed to run 'superset upgrade db' and then 'superset init'.  More details at the link.
